# Execution of C in linux

Tags: c, linux, compilation, execution

I am programming in NDK for android and it got me thinking. I know C is platform independent language but compiler dependent. With that in mind how does the execution of a C program vary from Windows->Linux->Mac. I mean the source code produces .obj file and .exe file in windows. But how about Linux or Mac? What type of file extension does it follow in Linux and Mac. If someone could elaborate on this, I would be very happy.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux and MacOs (Unix System) the files have the extension .c and to execute this you should compile them with

```
gcc -o myprog myprog.c
```

after it a binary file .o will be product and after you can run it with the file : myprog

by using this line of command :

```
./myprog
```

see how linux work if you are interesting by this you can read about Linux things like POSIX

I hope I have explain you the best way. (sorry i'm french :( )